# Persistence of already viewed activity changes on the profile page

Tags: support, recent-activity, notification-bar

This has always confused me. I'm not sure if it's a deliberate design that takes reputation points into account (for some reason), or a bug.

When I get responses and/or new reputation points, the top-right notification bar lights up. If I open the respective drop down menus, the notification is removed -- so far so good.

But when I visit the profile page, if it's a site I recently joined and have few reputation points there, the *activity* bar would be cleared (as expected because I have already viewed the changes via the notification bar). But on sites where I have a higher number of reputation points, the activity bar remains lit up with the changes I had already cleared from the notification bar (example below):

[image]
(Screenshot shows what I mean by activity bar)

Unless there's a point to it, it becomes annoying having to clear the recent activity twice (top-right notification bar, and the activity bar under the profile).

What's the point of it persisting like that (double clear required) unless it's a site I have recently joined?